# Java Servlet Response Form

Tags: java, http, servlets, jakarta-ee, java-ee-7

I am working on a project where I have to modify a Java Servlet application to add additional fields for the user to enter information. Then after the "Submit" button is pressed, the response should appear on the same page as the initial field page. My issue is, the response page is not appearing. The response page should show what the user entered in the initial page but currently, my initial page just clears the input fields and the response never shows. I am very new still to Java, so if you see anything else that I need to improve on, please let me know! Below is my current code:

hello2 greeting:

```html
package javaeetutorial.hello2;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/greeting")
public class GreetingServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.setContentType("text/html");
        response.setBufferSize(8192);
        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
            out.println("<html lang=\"en\">"
                    + "<head><title>Servlet Hello</title></head>");

            out.println("<body  bgcolor=\"#ffffff\">"
                    + "<img src=\"resources/images/duke.waving.gif\" "
                    + "alt=\"Duke waving his hand\">"
                    + "<form method=\"get\">"
                    + "<h2>Please complete our Customer Survey</h2>"
                    + "<h3>First name:</h3>"
                    + "<input title=\"First Name \" type=\"text\" "
                    + "fname=\"firstname\" size=\"25\"/>"
                    + "<h4>Last name:</h4>"
                    + "<input title=\"lastname\" type=\"text\" "
                    + "lname=\"lastname\" size=\"25\"/>"
                    + "<h5>E-mail:</h5>"
                    + "<input title=\"E-mail \" type=\"text\" "
                    + "emailaddress=\"email\" size=\"25\"/>"
                    + "<h6>Birth date:</h6>"
                    + "<input title=\"Birthday \" type=\"text\" "
                    + "bdate=\"birthdate\" size=\"25\"/>"
                    + "<p></p>"
                    + "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Submit\"/>"
                    + "<input type=\"reset\" value=\"Reset\"/>"
                    + "</form>");

            String firstname = request.getParameter("fname");
            String lastname = request.getParameter("lname");
            String email = request.getParameter("emailaddress");
            String birthdate = request.getParameter("bdate");

            if (firstname != null && firstname.length() > 0) {

                RequestDispatcher dispatcher
                        = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/response");

                if (dispatcher != null) {
                    dispatcher.include(request, response);
                }
            }
            if (lastname != null && lastname.length() > 0) {
                RequestDispatcher dispatcher
                        = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/response");

                if (dispatcher != null) {
                    dispatcher.include(request, response);
                }
            }
            if (email != null && email.length() > 0) {
                RequestDispatcher dispatcher
                        = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/response");

                if (dispatcher != null) {
                    dispatcher.include(request, response);
                }
            }
            if (birthdate != null && birthdate.length() > 0) {
                RequestDispatcher dispatcher
                        = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/response");

                if (dispatcher != null) {
                    dispatcher.include(request, response);
                }
            }
            out.println("</body></html>");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "The Hello servlet says hello.";
    }

}
```

hello2 response:

```html
package javaeetutorial.hello2;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/response")
public class ResponseServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
            out.println("Thank you for completing our Customer Survey form on !");
            String firstname = request.getParameter("firstname");
            String lastname = request.getParameter("lastname");
            String email = request.getParameter("email");
            String birthdate = request.getParameter("birthdate");
            
            if (firstname != null && firstname.length() > 0) {
                out.println("<h2>First name: " + firstname + "</h2>");
            }
            if (lastname != null && lastname.length() > 0) {
                out.println("<h3>Last name: " + lastname + "</h3>");
            }
            if (email != null && email.length() > 0) {
                out.println("<h4>E-mail address: " + email + "</h4>");
            }
            if (birthdate != null && birthdate.length() > 0) {
                out.println("<h5>Birth date: " + birthdate + "</h5>");
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "The Response servlet says hello.";

    }
}
```

Comment: just call the dispatcher,include only once right before the </body> closing tag. And use parentheses in the conditions (this is just a guess)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was too small..you forgot the **action** attribute of the form.Due to this,your response was not being send to RespponseServlet.
It was supposed to be like this

```
<form action='response' method=\"get\">
```

Comment: I was able to get the response page to show up but I am having trouble with my input fields. The input fields are not storing the user entered information so it's showing as null. Any advise?

Comment: You misunderstood how parameter's values are passed to server with request.  request.getParameter() checks the name attribute of the fields.So when you use req.getParameter("firstname");, then the input field which has attribute (name="firstname") will be be searched,but since there is no such attribute ,there for it will return null.To correct it, add attribute name="firstname" and so on..

Comment: Ahh!! I get where I misunderstood! Thank you guys! I got the application to work perfectly!